# Order of arguments in Symfony controller with autowiring

Tags: php, symfony

When using autowiring in Symfony and injecting services into a controller, is there a best practice for the order of the arguments? In other words, should arguments for injected services come before or after arguments for route params?

Symfony docs seem to be inconsistent on this. [In this example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#fetching-services), they show the route param coming before the injected service. However, [in this example](http://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#the-request-object-as-a-controller-argument), they show it the other way around.

I'm leaning towards always injecting services first, so I can give route parameters a default value:

```
public function someAction(Request $request, MyService $myService, $id = 0)
```

Also, this just looks wrong to me:

```
public function someAction(Request $request, $id, MyService $myService)
```

I've googled and searched stack overflow, but haven't seen any other answers on this. I found it a little bit odd, as I feel like consistency with these things are important (perhaps I'm going a little overboard here and it really doesn't matter?)

Comment: I've read somewhere that the best practice would be putting optional arguments last, but for the sake of it I cannot find it anywhere.

Comment: It's not really a best practice.  php requires you to place optional arguments at the of the function.  Once an optional argument is encountered, php requires all following arguments to be optional.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter, if you set default values via annotation. If you set default value at argument directly, then here is only one choose - put optional arguments last.
Important part is uniform code style.

Comment: Right, obviously arguments with a default value have to come last, and uniform code style is important. My question is more around if symfony has a best practice or perferred way for this.

Comment: Didn't find anything, I think this is simple enough and because of that they didn't mention order of arguments in autowiring docs.